# How to Access AWS EC2 docker tomcat instance running inside jenkins docker instance from my local browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, jenkins, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a jenkins instance running inside a docker container that's listening on port 8181.

Example URL of the jenkins instance:
http://ec2-34-155-164-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

I have a tomcat docker instance that's listening on port 8383 running inside the jenkins docker container.

I can access jenkins instance from my local browser. Is there any possible way that I can access my docker tomcat instance from my local browser?

Here is my `docker run` command:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -p 8181:8080 jenkins-dsl
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: FYI your Jenkins server is open to the world...As for your question, it's difficult to answer without knowing what kind of environment or _how_ your jenkins docker container is running (i.e. are you running it manually with `docker run`? is it on ECS?)

Comment: I am running it manually with docker run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `docker run` command simply needs to expose the port that your nested tomcat server is running on.

To do this, you need to pass in `-p` argument into your command. The `-p` argument is for binding a host port to the docker container's port:

```
-p <host_port>:<container_port>
```

You can pass in as many `-p` arguments as you want to bind multiple ports.

So if the docker tomcat server is running on port 8383 *within* the Jenkins docker container, then you can do something like this:

```
-p 8383:8080
```

Full command example:

```
docker run -d -it -p 8383:8080 --name tomcatServer docker-tomcat
```

I would assume that this would allow you to access tomcat server using the example URL provided like so:

http://ec2-34-155-164-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8383

However, you'd have to ensure your AWS Security Group will allow traffic to port 8383.

EDIT: Updated answer to reflect the resolution we discussed in the comments.
Edited

Comment: @ricardgirges : Thanks for this. But It doesnt seems to be working.

Comment: @ricardgirges : Thanks for this. But It doesnt seems to be working. May be I would have mentioned this earlier. I have a  job in  jenkins instance which builds and runs the tomcat image. docker run -d -it -p 8383:8080 --name tomcatServer docker-tomcat.  I followed the above procedure now I am getting .8383 failed: port is already allocated.

Comment: I usually do localhost:8383 from my browser to access tomcat locally. what if I do samething like this http://ec2-34-155-164-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8383. But How to configure the security for that in aws.

Comment: Are you using an EC2 instance? If so look at the EC2 instance's details and find out what Security Group is attached to it. Then modify that Security Group to open up port 8383.

Comment: I am using EC2 instance - ubuntu. I have opened the security group in EC2.

Comment: Do i need to change something on the host file to listen to port 8383 as well.?

Comment: Not if your docker container binds to port 8383. If your Jenkins job is starting the container and passing in -p 8383:8080 then that should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine. I enable the port 8383 in EC2 instance

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the resolution we came to in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to launch tomcat by specifying the port in the URL and opening the port in EC2 instance.

http://ec2-34-155-164-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8383

Answer (score 0):

Latest  Docker installation guide for Tomcat clearly says you will get this error when you launch it for the first time

```
You can then go to http://localhost:8888 or http://host-ip:8888 in a browser (noting that it will return a 404 since there are no webapps loaded by default).
```

its because you do not have any apps in the default webapps folder of Tomcat. your latest Tomcat  docker image has the default apps in the "webapps.dist" folder, you have to copy it to "webapps" folder. Do the Following commands

```
#  docker exec -it tomcat-container /bin/bash
#  cd webapps.dist
#  cp -R * ../webapps
```

"tomcat-container" is your container name.
now refresh your browser you will get it. if not let me know